# How do I read arbitrary bytes from a zlib stream?

Tags: c, zlib, inflate

I would like to read the output of a zlib stream's `inflate()` into a buffer one byte at a time, so that I can parse out single lines.

Is there a way to specify the number of bytes that `inflate()` returns, so that I can watch for newlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would probably give horrible performance, since the `inflate()` function might have some start up costs.

I would suggest just going with a reasonable output buffer size, and then iterating through the buffer after each call to `inflate()`, collecting all complete lines found. Of course there will very likely be a "tail", i.e. an incomplete line, that you will need to keep track of for the next round.

Comment: Yes, that's a good approach, however lot of care should be taken to not read beyond results actually obtained by unpacking and into uninitialized whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's a bit of a pain to do the bookkeeping, but it seems to work. The trick is to make sure not to read past `zStream.avail_out` and to null-terminate the buffer at that point — it is this clipped buffer that needs to be parsed for newlines. Still, I have set up a large buffer and it runs fairly speedily.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `inflate()` you pass a pointer to a `z_stream_s` structure. `z_stream_s::avail_out` member variable of that structure is exactly for specifying the size of the output buffer.